# Excel VBA Subtotal not subtotalling

Tags: vba, excel, subtotal

I am trying to use the Subtotal function in VBA within Microsoft Office Excel 2013/2016. I am using the following code:

```
'Copies mostly formatted Report to new Sheet for Report
'Sheets("Report").Select
Sheets("Report").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
Worksheets(4).Select
Worksheets(4).Name = "Report2"

'Modifies Date column to count days worked instead
Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Days Worked"
Range("D2").Select
Range("D2").NumberFormat = "0"
Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D2500")

'Generates subtotals for Days Worked, Calls Taken, Call time, nextcallwaiting time, calls held, and time calls on hold
Worksheets(4).Activate
Range("E1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=3, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(4, 6, 8, 10 _
                                                                          , 12, 14), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

'ungroups these rows to allow easy data manipulation
Range("C1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Activate
Selection.Rows.Ungroup
Selection.Rows.Ungroup    '
```

Picture of errored result (not expected) included.

I expect the Subtotals function to make subtotals.... could it be it's operating too quickly to correctly find and add same agents statistics together?

I am expecting it to total columns in the attached manner (See "Days Worked" column. If an agent worked more than one day, it has multiple "1 Day Worked" lines, but didn't combine them during the subtotal operation), but it is not totaling the columns as the Subtotal function should. What am I doing wrong? What is the workaround for this error?

---

### Column B: Supervisor of Agent in C

### -Column C: Agent (call center employee)

### -Column D: Days Worked (How many days did they work last week?

### -Column E: Login (Employee login; examples given in screenshot)

### -Column F: Calls handled (how many calls they took)

### -Column G: Average time spent per call [HH]:MM:SS format

### -Column H: Total time on calls [HH]:MM:SS format

### -Column I: A time in [HH]:MM:SS format

### -Column J: A time in [HH]:MM:SS format

### -Column K: Column figured later (intentionally blank)

[image]

EDIT: This has been resolved. For using the Subtotal VBA, you must have your separating term/entity (In this case, Agent Name) grouped together. So, going down the column you must sort largest>smallest, A>Z, or something similar so that these similar records are close together ***PRIOR*** to performing the Subtotal VBA. Thank you to all who were looking into this issue!

Comment: Did you check on which range the subtotal was applied? (For instance by including `MsgBox  (Selection.Address)` just before the line with the `.Subtotal` ).  And was that the range you were expecting?

Comment: I did. I also stepped through the code manually. Started from A1, then selecting cells to the right and all cells down is selecting the correct range (All cells) and using the correct range for the subtotal function array entries (4, 6, 8, etc.).

Comment: Please review edit at bottom of post now - resolution has been reached.

Comment: Yes, great, that is the solution! Makes it possible to make the code more readable and maintainable. That leaves only the last part, with the 2 `.UnGroup` statements ... How do we know that 2 levels will always be enough?

Comment: (.. after having looked at that UnGroup part for more than an hour) Finally found that there is a method for that: Try this: `[C1].CurrentRegion.ClearOutline` ...

Comment: Thanks, Peter. It's just a great headache that this isn't specified on the MSDN documentation (I'm proposing an edit now through MS Discussions). Regarding the UnGroup part, I appreciate that solution and may use it in future projects! In regards to this one, I know that there will always be to groupings to remove, so the static approach used in my sample above is fine with me! Thank you again for following up on this!

Comment: Out of curiosity, since I'm always grouping by the third column (which in this range will always be Column C), couldn't we assume that there will always be two groupings because of Columns A & Columns B? Or does it determine the number of groupings a different way? All thoughts appreciated!

Comment: I don't know. I've never used excel subtotals before yesterday. But according to the documentation, Subtotals in excel can only group by one field, so I assume that you're correct and that there won't be more than 2 added levels when using this method.

Comment: I would transition to chat if able; only one reputation so far. If you have the time, try doing something with 15 columns and grouping by the 10th column. See if you have 9 groupings result or something else. I'm quite curious - about to hit the road for entire day or I would do it myself.